# Error in application: ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing ORA-01843: not a valid month - Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a problem in Oracle Apex tool. Namely, I was making a table reservation application and I wanted to print all reservations under a specific date. So I choose the date under which I want to print all bookings, press the print button, and Apex throws me the following error:

> ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing ORA-01843: not a valid
>   month.

Previously, I had neatly added AOP and a word document.

In the right window, I selected in SQL data type: SQL, and in code data I put the code.
Later I added "TO DATE in code", but that doesn't fix my problem.

Here is the code:

```
select 
    'file1' as "filename",
    cursor(select
        TO_DATE(D.SIFRA_DATUMA_REZERVACIJE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "datum_rezervacije",
        cursor(select
            R.SIFRA_REZERVACIJE as "sifra_rezervacije", 
            G.IME_PREZIME as "ime_prezime", 
            R.BROJ_OSOBA as "broj_osoba",
            S.SIFRA_STOLA as "broj_stola",
            R.NAPOMENA_REZERVACIJE as "napomena",
            P.NAZIV_PRIGODE as "prigoda"
            from 
        GOST G, PRIGODA P, STOL S, REZERVACIJA R   where 
            R.SIFRA_GOST_REZERVACIJA = G.SIFRA_GOSTA
            and R.SIFRA_STOL_REZERVACIJA = S.SIFRA_STOLA
            and R.SIFRA_PRIGODE_REZERVACIJA = P.SIFRA_PRIGODE 
            and TO_DATE(R.SIFRA_DATUM_REZERVACIJE_REZERVACIJA, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) = TO_DATE(:P6_NEW, 'MM/DD/YYYY') order by TO_DATE(R.SIFRA_DATUM_REZERVACIJE_REZERVACIJA, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) as "rezervacija"
        from
        DATUM_REZERVACIJE D  
        where 
        TO_DATE(D.SIFRA_DATUMA_REZERVACIJE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')= TO_DATE(:P6_NEW, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) as "data" 
from dual;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Show us the input data, is the date format of `:P6_NEW` really `MM/DD/YYYY`? Then **NEVER** call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`.

Comment: What is the data type for the column named `R.SIFRA_DATUM_REZERVACIJE_REZERVACIJA`? Also, what is the value of the bind variable `P6_NEW` when you run the query? You can use the session button in the Developer Toolbar when running the app (if your authenticated as a developer) to view the value of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is in "american style" but the language the column name specified on is obviously not english. Could it be that you're converting date into wrong format and the 'dd/mm/yyyy' is the right format to be used here?

For example, insert 30 of December in the table first

```
insert into some_table(date_col) values(to_date('30/12/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

then this (see the date format) will cause the same you are experiencing - not a valid month

```
select to_date(date_col, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from some_table;
```